# reloadData doesn't work after parsing with Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, reloaddata

Though I assigned value(self) to delegate/dataSource, reloadData doesn't work.
So, I set breakpoint, its dataSource hasn't the data.
How do I work reloadData? Here is my example code.

```
func getData(query: String) {
    // ...(data processing part)
    var parser: NSXMLParser! = NSXMLParser(data: data)
    parser.delegate = self
    parser.parse() // parsing works well.
    self.testTableView.hidden = false // breakpoint 1
    self.testTableView.dataSource = self
    self.testTableView.delegate = self
    self.testTableView.reloadData() 
    // breakpoint 2
    insertTableWithConstraint() // set constraints
    // init. dataSource
    self.testTableView.dataSource = nil
}
```

I tried both "self.testTableView.~" and "testTableView.~", but It didn't work.
 Here is variable sets in my breakpoint

> testTableView = (UITableView) 00000001360dee00
>  some = (UITableView) 0x00000001360dee00
>   ...
>   _dataSource = (sunny.TestViewController *)0x135d34950
>    [0] (sunny.TestViewController)
>   ...
> testDatas = (NSMutableArray) "4 values"

I append the my CellForRowAtIndex code.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell: UITableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel.text = testDatas.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("title") as NSString
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = testData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("roadAddress") as NSString
    NSLog("cell.textLabel.text : \(cell.textLabel.text)") // It was not shown in exec.
    NSLog("cell.detailTextLabel.text : \(cell.detailTextLabel?.text)") // It was not shown in exec.
    return cell as UITableViewCell
}
```

I forgot to append the numberOfRowsInSection code. So I append it.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return testDatas.count
}
```

Comment: Why are you setting `self.testTableView.dataSource = nil` ?  that will clear your table

Comment: Show your cellForRowAtIndexpath & numberOfRow method.

Comment: provide your tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath code

Comment: I set nil to dataSource because It crashed when I tabbed back button.

Comment: Well, don't set datasource to nil.

Comment: I delete 'set datasource to nil'. but reloadData doesn't work. not crashed.

Comment: What is `numberOfRowsInSection` as @Rashad asked

Comment: Ah... I'll append it. it is so simple code.

Comment: Have you set a break point in `numberOfRowsInSection` and/or in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` ?  Are these functions called?

Comment: I set a breakpoint in nuberOfRowsInSection or cellForRowAtIndexPath, but nothing happened.

Comment: I tried again, numberOfRowsInSection called but not called cellForRowAtIndexPath. Why?

Answer (score 0):

1) You shouldn't call `self.testTableView.dataSource = nil`. If your app crashes without it, it probably means you're trying to access your data without first checking it is not empty.

2) I assume that your `NSXMLParser` is used to populate your `UITableView` rows. `NSXMLParser` works with a delegate mechanism, so you should call `testTableView.reloadData()` only when you're done parsing, not immediately like you're doing right now. A good place to call it would be in the `parserDidEndDocument` delegate function.

3) In your `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` function, check that `indexPath` corresponds to something accessible in your `testDatas` variable (which I assume is built during XML parsing). This might be why your app is crashing right now.

4) Also, be careful to appropriately set the cell count in the `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int` delegate function (probably using `testDatas.count`).

Comment: Thanks, I placed reloadData but It doesn't work. I set a breakpoint in cellForRowIndexPath. Nothing happens.

Comment: also I delete "self.testTableView.dataSource = nil", not crashed.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in `parserDidEndDocument` and check that it is getting called?

Comment: Yes, It called parseDidEndDocument and reloadData, so called numberOfRowsInSection, but not called cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Does `numberOfRowsInSection` eventually returns `0`? (for whatever reason)

Comment: At first, It returns 0. After parsing it returns 4 normally.

Comment: If `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not called but `numberOfRowsInSection` is, it might be a problem with how your `UITableView` is setup in the view. Can you tell us what `insertTableWithConstraint()` does? Also, explain from where `getData()` is being called. Is it from `viewDidLoad()`? `viewWillAppear()`? Somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't set, tableview's `dataSource` & `delegate` to `nil`, set them to `self`.

As you said your `numberOfRowsInSection` returns exact count of the datasource object. Then try this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel.text = testDatas.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("title") as NSString
    return cell
}
```

Hope this helps.. :)